# ListView strange behavoiur with blend trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have simple ListView with trigger also I am using mvvm light RelayCommand.
The main question is why when function `ChangeShowingMode(ObservableCollection<Employee> items)` fires in console it displays only `Firing: 0`. Why it do not show also `Firing: 1`,`Firing: 5`,`Firing: 11`,`Firing: 99`. How to make it?

> xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
>   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ei:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <ei:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <ei:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.IsCheckedTrueCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Views:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </ei:EventTrigger>
                        </ei:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </CheckBox>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code Looks like:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ListViewModel();
    }
}
public class Employee : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isChecked = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> items;
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.items;
        }

        set
        {
            this.items = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public ListViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        LoadAsync();
    }
    public void LoadAsync()
    {
        Task t = null;
        t = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            ObservableCollection<Employee> temporaryItems = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                temporaryItems.Add(new Employee { IsChecked = false, Name = i.ToString() });
            }
            Items = temporaryItems;
        }));
        t.ContinueWith((key) => { ChangeShowingMode(Items); });
    }
    public void ChangeShowingMode(ObservableCollection<Employee> items)
    {
        Items[0].IsChecked = true;
        Items[1].IsChecked = true;
        Items[5].IsChecked = true;
        Items[11].IsChecked = true;
        Items[99].IsChecked = true;
    }

    public RelayCommand<Employee> IsCheckedTrueCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<Employee>((emp) => Command(emp));
        }
    }

    public void Command(Employee emp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Firing: {0}", emp.Name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Assuming that `IsChecked` raises `INPC.PropertyChanged` event I'm guessing it's to do with that you do you it from `Task`. You can change `Employee.IsChecked` property on any theread by `PropertyChanged` event should be raise on UI thread (via `Dispatcher`)

Comment: You are wrong because t.ContinueWith((key) => { ChangeShowingMode(Items); });
     raising on UI thread. I Think problem is with virtualization or something else of this kind.

Comment: No it doesn't. Not until you specify appropriate `TaskScheduler`, for example `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

Comment: Okay if it updat not on UI tread why it does not throws exceptions?

Comment: Why would it. You just raise event. Log to console current thread ID from before and in continue with

Comment: I added changes that you suggested but it do not help. It does not rise in console.

Comment: Based on your code you already have it working if user does it form UI by checking the Checkbox. But When u check it from VM your code doesnot call Command. Like others said you need to Call Command 
IsCheckedTrueCommand.Execute(Items[0]);
.
.
.
IsCheckedTrueCommand.Execute(Items[99]); 
Whenever u do it from VM u need to do this. 
Also, whenever your Task runs your updates to UI Bound controls will not get notification neither exception. So you need to call it in Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Checked Event will raise only for visible Checkboxes. So the command is only called for the visible ones.

[image: sample UI]

By test your provided example, the Properties are set by the task and also reflected as expected by the UI. But the Command is only called, when I manually check a checkbox, not through initialisation.

Changing

```
t.ContinueWith((key) => { ChangeShowingMode(Items); });
```

to

```
t.ContinueWith((key) => { Syste.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); ChangeShowingMode(Items); });
```

has the result, that the Command is called for the visible Checkboxes.
If you scoll down when the checkboxes are displayed, the command is called for Checkbox 99.

But this behavior isn't strange at all. I think, it is a timming-Issue when your viewmodel is connected to the Datacontext or not.

The answer to your question "How to make it?" depends on what is your problem with the current solution.

To watch the property changes, you could 
[How to Listen to Property Changes of Items of an ObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang) 
and call a command on changes.

But I think you don't need this at all. The checked-State is reflected by your IsChecked-Property through the Two-Way binding.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

So you can easily get them by

```
var checkedItemsList = Items.Where(ele => ele.IsChecked).ToList();
```

And if you make Changes by Code, you can call the Command manually in your viewmodel.

```
Items[0].IsChecked = true;
if (IsCheckedTrueCommand.CanExecute(Items[0]))
    IsCheckedTrueCommand.Execute(Items[0]);
```

But I'm not sure if I get you here. The question remains what the command should do in an enhanced scenario.

Btw, which Version of Framework you are using? See [check box binding not working on .NET 3.5 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602737/why-is-my-wpf-checkbox-binding-not-working)

And to call a Comand on User-Interaction you can use:

```
<CheckBox CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckBoxCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Comment: Replace in my code t.ContinueWith((key) => { ChangeShowingMode(Items); }); with t.ContinueWith((key) => { Syste.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); ChangeShowingMode(Items); }); And i think it will also wonder you.:)

Comment: @A191919 I checked this, see my updated answer.  Happy new year!